# How to identify each instance of a data-frame with normalized vectors into quantiles (like 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75,1)?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data-frame with 20 variables and 400k instances. All variables are normalized with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. I want to write a function which could classify each instance of each variables into quantiles.

```
Lets say we have a normalized vector
a <- c(0.2132821 -1.5136988  0.6450274  1.5085178  0.2132821  1.5085178  0.6450274)

And the quantiles for this vector are
quant.a <- c(-1.5136988 -1.0819535  0.2132821  1.0767726  1.5085178)

where -1.5136988 is 0%
      -1.0819535 is 25%
       0.2132821 is 50%
       1.0767726 is 75%
       1.5085178 is 100% (all are elements in vector 'quant.a')

Now, I want to classify each element of vector 'a' as follows
new.a <- c(0.5, 0, 0.75, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.75)

You can use the following code to workout through the example as it is not possible for me to share the actual data

# Generate random data
set.seed(99)

# All variables are on a scale of 1-9
a <- floor(runif(500, min = 1, max = 9))
b <- floor(runif(500, min = 1, max = 9))
c <- floor(runif(500, min = 1, max = 9))

# store variables as dataframe
x <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))

#Scale variables
scaled.dat <- data.frame(scale(x))

# check that we get mean of 0 and sd of 1
colMeans(scaled.dat)  
apply(scaled.dat, 2, sd)

# generate quantiles for each variables
quantiles <- data.frame(apply(scaled.dat,2,quantile))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
yourdataframe %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(ntile(., 4)/4)
```

Comment: Hey Brian! Its a great way to find the ith quantile (as in quantile 1, quantile 2 ,.... so on). But I was looking for the output to be of the form (0, .25, .5, .75, 1). But anyways Thank you. Always good to learn new stuff

Comment: @Nikhil, you just have to include `/4` to get that representation. If you want more explicit labeling, you can use `percent_rank` instead and then another call to `mutate_all(funs(cut(., 0:4/4)))`

Answer (score 2):

```
a <- c(0.2132821, -1.5136988,  0.6450274 , 1.5085178 , 0.2132821 , 1.5085178 , 0.6450274)

quant.a = quantile(a)

aux_matrix = findInterval(a, quant.a)

new.a = ifelse(aux_matrix == 1|aux_matrix == 0, 0, 
               ifelse(aux_matrix == 2, 0.5,
                      ifelse(aux_matrix==3,0.75,
                             1)))

print(new.a)

0.50 0.00 0.75 1.00 0.50 1.00 0.75
```

Comment: `temp = findInterval(a, quant.a); as.numeric(gsub("%", "", names(quant.a)[ifelse(temp == 1, 1, pmin(length(quant.a), temp+1))]))/100`

Comment: Thank you Alexey!! works perfectly the way I intended it to.

Comment: Hey d.b! tried you way. Its still off by 1 quantile. Like instead of .25 it gives .5 on my data-frame. But I will try to figure out whats causing that. And Thank you for your help.

Comment: Those are boundary conditions issues. When a quantile is the same as one of the array values. Hence I put in "0" quantile, when `a` equals the `quant.a[1]`

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you Alexey. Check out Brian's way as well.Its quite generic.